# JSON to C# Classes - Unknown property names

Tags: c#, .net, json

let's say I have the following JSON payload;

```
  {
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "msapplication-task": "name\u003dAbout Tugberk Ugurlu;action-uri\u003d/about;icon-uri\u003d/content/App_Icons/icos/about.ico",
      "msapplication-task": "name\u003dContact;action-uri\u003d/contact;icon-uri\u003d/content/App_Icons/icos/contact.ico",
      "msapplication-task": "name\u003dBlog RSS Feed;action-uri\u003dhttp://feeds.feedburner.com/TugberkUgurlu;icon-uri\u003d/content/App_Icons/icos/rss.ico",
      "msapplication-task": "name\u003dTugberk on Twitter;action-uri\u003dhttp://twitter.com/tourismgeek;icon-uri\u003d/content/App_Icons/icos/twitter.ico",
      "msapplication-starturl": "./",
      "application-name": "Tugberk's Blog",
      "msapplication-tooltip": "bla bla bla..."
     }
    ]
   }
  }
```

The property names under mettags are dynamic. I mean one of them is `msapplication-starturl` for this request but it might be `msapplication-foo` for another.

So what would be the best c# classes for this kind of JSON payload?

**EDIT**

this is the part of JSON format which google search API gives. Also I am using Json.NET. is There any other way than dynamic?

Comment: The only somewhat somewhat-typed way that can be *statically represented* represented is `IDictionary<JSONKey,JSONValueSuperType>` (as a sequence element of `metatags`) or similar -- of course, if this dynamic nature only applies to "msapplication-" ... but why make it even more confusing? :) I'm honestly not really sure what is being asked otherwise :-/

Comment: @pst this is the part of JSON format which google search API gives. Also I am using Json.NET. There isn't any other way than dynamic, is it?

Comment: @pst I think the question is pretty clear. Also it's very easy to understand that the metatags contains the page metetags. so it will be highly possible that they will be different.

Comment: @tugberk Then see my comment. Alternatively, consider a JSON mechanism that allows/uses `dynamic`.

Comment: Doesn't json require the keys in a dictionary to be unique? Is that even valid json?

Comment: @CodeInChaos ask Google. it is their stuff. msapplication-task things are meta tags which google also indexed

Comment: Duplicate keys have a few problems. 1) You can't use a normal dictionary anymore 2) Json parsers might not cope with it well, since it's a violation of the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably just want the MetaTags array to just get pushed into a `Dictionary<string,string>` or even just `List<string>` and then write a helper class that parses `msapplication-task` values into something you want.

**Edit:** I believe the OP is looking for some help in how his model class would actually be

```
public class PageMap
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> MetaTags {get;set; }
}
```

From looking at that json object, it appears that RestSharp should be able to deserialize it into this class.

Calling code would be similar to

```
var client = new RestClient("somegoogle.com");
var request = new RestRequest("Some/Foo/Bar", Method.GET)
                                 { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json }; 
request.AddParameter("p1", "quigybo");
client.Execute<PageMan>(request)
```

Comment: @tugberk - Dictionary<TKey, TValue> *is* a class.

Comment: @Greg so it would be this : `public Dictionary<string, string> Metatags { get; set; }` ?

Comment: IMO a public setter for a property that has a mutable type(like Dictionary) is rarely a good idea. I'd make the the setter private.

Comment: @CodeInChaos the OP would need to verify whether that is a viable option for JSON.NET serialization (that RestSharp uses)

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [JSON.NE](http://json.codeplex.com/)T and [JObject](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) for building dynamic loosely typed objects.  If you decide to use it, you should [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) to download it.

Example:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "your user agent here");
var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.domain.com/source-page.html"));
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(response);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning direct JObects, RestSharp is biult on top of JSON.NET so the OP has that implicitly.

Comment: I had never heard of JObject. Cheers mate, very useful response :-)